# Trace operator is basis independent

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and call suppose $A:H\rightarrow H$ is positive. How do you show Tr$(A)=\sum_{n}(Ae_n,e_n)$, does not depends on the orthonormal basis $e_n$.

I was thinking about using an approximation of $A$ as $A_k$ where $A_k$ is finite rank operator, so $Tr(A_k)$ is the sum of diagonal entries of an $\infty\times n$ matrix, which is basis independent. Then use $Tr(A_k)\rightarrow Tr(A)$ to conclude the proof. Is this the right approach?

Comment: It seems to me that in a not finite dimensional Hilbert space the trace is defined only for **trace class** operators, and this class id defined as operators such that $||A||=\sum _i\langle Ae_i,e_i\rangle$ is absolutely convergent and independent of the basis.

Comment: Since the operator is assumed to be positive, you can define a well-defined trace in this manner, however the range is $[0,\infty]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\{e_n\}$ and $\{f_k\}$ are orthonormal bases of $H$. Then you can write
$$ \tag 1 x = \sum_k (x,f_k) f_k$$
and 
$$ \tag 2 y = \sum_n (y,e_n) e_n$$
for all $x,y \in H$. Evaluate (1) with $x = Ae_n$ to find
$$ Ae_n = \sum_k (Ae_n,f_k) f_k $$
so that
$$ \sum_n (Ae_n,e_n) = \sum_n \sum_k (Ae_n,f_k)(f_k,e_n).$$
Next evaluate (2) with $y = f_k$ and then apply $A$ to find
$$Af_k = \sum_n (f_k,e_n)Ae_n$$
so that
$$ \sum_k(Af_k,f_k) = \sum_k \sum_n (f_k,e_n)(Ae_n,f_k)$$

Thus $\displaystyle \sum_n (Ae_n,e_n) = \sum_k(Af_k,f_k)$ provided that you can switch the order of summation which will require some condition on $A$.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I appreciated. This is how start the argument then I got stuck in the algebra :('

Comment: The proof seems to not exploit the assuption of being trace class. However there is a counterexample for this case: [Basis Indepence?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1486733/79762)

Comment: The problem with this "proof" is precisely in showing that the interchange of summations is admissible. I have never seen a convincing argument to this effect -- unless of course the space is finite dimensional. I've come to the conclusion that the proof of basis invariance of the trace using the square root of positive operators, found in most books, is the only one.

Comment: @M.Mueger to be honest I don't disagree. But it is a 7 year old answer and at the time it seemed like a helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Note for positive sums:
$$a_{\alpha\beta}\geq0:\quad\sum_\alpha\sum_\beta a_{\alpha\beta}=\sum_\beta\sum_\alpha a_{\alpha\beta}$$

By Parseval one has:
$$\sum_\sigma\langle|A|\sigma,\sigma\rangle=\sum_\sigma\||A|^{1/2}\sigma\|^2=\sum_\sigma\sum_\tau|\langle|A|^{1/2}\sigma,\tau\rangle|^2\\
=\sum_\tau\sum_\sigma|\langle\sigma,|A|^{1/2}\tau\rangle|^2=\sum_\tau\||A|^{1/2}\tau\|^2=\sum_\tau\langle|A|\tau,\tau\rangle$$

Concluding independence.

Comment: Since Tonelli's theorem asumes $\sigma$-finite spaces, and this is used in the first line of the proof, is this proof limited to the case where $H$ is separable?

Comment: The first line uses lim=sup where limit runs over finite sums (finite subsets of the indexing subset). But suprema of positive elements always interchange.

Comment: Added argument: (any of the above sums being finite) implies that (there are at most countably many non-zero terms.)