# Trace Class: Counterexample

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

*This is a real question!*

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Denote trace class by:*
$$\mathcal{B}_\textrm{Tr}(\mathcal{H}):=\{A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\operatorname{Tr}|A|<\infty\}$$

Then it seems wrong:
$$A,B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad BA\in\mathcal{B}_\textrm{Tr}(\mathcal{H})\implies AB\in\mathcal{B}_\textrm{Tr}(\mathcal{H})$$

Have a counterexample?

**Remind: [Definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1213342/79762)*

Comment: Why do you think that it is wrong?

Comment: @Hetebrij: At least it is not clear why it should hold true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a counterexample:
Let $\mathcal{H} = \ell^2\oplus\ell^2$. Define $A, B\  \colon \ \ell^2 \oplus \ell^2 \to \ell^2 \oplus \ell^2$ by
$$A(u, v) = (u, 0) \quad\text{and}\quad B(u, v) = (v, 0).$$
Then
$$BA(u, v) = (0, 0) \quad\text{and}\quad AB(u, v) = (v, 0).$$
Thus $BA$ is a trace class operator but $AB$ is not a trace class operator.

Comment: Nice, great thanks!!! :)